# WebStorm Auto import - "require" instead of "import from"

Tags: node.js, webstorm

Working on a Node.js project I get suggestions (<kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd>) to import using ES6 when my Node.js does not support the import statement. Can I add suggestions that use require? Auto import saves so much time...

[image: auto import]

The manipulateName method definition:

```
const manipulateName = (layout, method) => {
    layout.name = method(layout.name);
    return layout;
}
```

and ...

```
module.exports = {
    manipulateName,
 ...
}
```

Comment: make sure that **Missing require() statement** is enabled in **Settings | Editor | InspectionsJavaScript | Node.js** - this should normally be enough

Comment: Seems to be enabled

Comment: what does the `manipulateName` module definition in `parserLayout.js` look like?

Comment: Oh, I see, perhaps it is related to the definition. I've added the definition to the question.

Comment: still I get both `require()` and `import` suggestions when using your definition :( Can you share a sample project that shows up the issue?

Comment: Thanks! reproduced; see my answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please make sure that **Node.js Core** library is enabled for your project (**Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | Node.js and NPM, Node.js Core library**).

See **Missing require() statement** inspection (**Preferences | Editor | InspectionsJavaScript | Node.js**)  description:

```
Checks that all modules are referenced through "require()".
Suggests inserting the "require()" call.
Works only in files in the scope of "Node.js Core" JavaScript library.
```

Comment:  Good stuff, super helpful, thanks for the effort. Do you know why it adds "var" and not "const"? still I can replace all "var" definitions in the end. Cheers.

Comment: what IDE build do you use? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-27131 was fixed in 2017.2...

Comment: What library exactly? How do you add it?

Comment: please see the answer - it's Node.js Core library. In most recent versions, it's called **Coding assistance for Node.js** and (still) can be enabled in **Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | Node.js and NPM**

Answer (score 1):

Webstorm 2019.2.
In my case I tried to enable "Coding assistance for Node.js" but the following happened:
Check  "Coding assistance for Node.js" --> Ok --> Re-open "Node.js and NPM" --> Coding Assistance is not checked.

I did the following:
 1. Help --> Find Action --> Registry --> search for "nodejs.core.library.use.typings" --> disable it.
 2. File --> "Invalidate and Restart"
 3. Go To Terminal --> type:

```
  /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js install @types/node --ignore-scripts
```

4. Settings --> "Node.js and NPM" --> checked "Coding Assistance for Node.js"

Solved!
Check also [Jetbrains Issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-36436#)